# Deleting all related list when a record is deleted in lookup

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, delete

Good day everyone I have a problem in regards with deletion. This is my scenario. I have a custom object let say as `AccountParent__c`. I also created a lookup field in my `Account` object which is related to my `AccountParent__c` object. One `AccountParent__c` record has many `Accounts`.And what I want is that when I delete a `AccountParent__c` record, all account related to it will also be deleted.What is the best thing I have to do ? At the moment I've created a batch process for deleting the account and when there is a deletion for `AccountParent__c` record, a trigger will call the batch process for account deletion. But it seems it is not working. I guess the reason is that the `AccountParent__c` is already deleted but the batch process is still running.(I use batch because in my case there are possibilities that my related records are more than 10000)Do you have any idea how to solve my problem ? Below is a sample code for my trigger.

```
trigger deletionAcc on AccountParent__c (before delete) {
  for (AccountParent__c theold : Trigger.old) {

      // below is the batch use to delete all related list 
      delBatch b = new delBatch(String.valueOf(theold.Id)); 
      database.executebatch(b);
 }
}
```

please help.Thank you...

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the standard ParentId field in Account?

Comment: @Peter yeah. Actually the question I've given is just a sample but the concept is quite similar.

Comment: You can create Master Detail field  and choose option delete child record when parent record get deleted. if it suits you.

Comment: other wise query your child record in trigger and delete them in trigger in chunk of 10000

Comment: @TusharSharma I cant use a master Detail because not all account has a AccountParent__c. In regards with deleting the data inside trigger will I not hit some governor limit for that ? Can you give me a sample code that can possibly solve my problem ? thanks.

Comment: You can never make a standard object detail anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not writing complete code for you suppose you have

```
List<Account> accList ;// list of child record which we need to do delete 
if(accList.size() < 10000)
    delete accList;
else {
    while(accList.size() > 0) {
     integer count = 1;
     List<account> tempList = new Account();
     for(integer counter = 0 ; counter < accList.size()) {
         tempList.add(accList[counter]);
         accList.remove(remove);
         count++;
         if(count == 10000)
         break;
        }
       if(tempList.size() > 0)
          delete tempList;
    }
}
```

As it is not optimize code because it has DML inside for loop  but it will work for you.
**If you have more then millions record then you will hit the limit.**

Comment: Btw. Do you have any other idea how my batch process may be used ?

Comment: create a static List varable and pass all child record id in the list now in your batch query all record using id and then delete record in chunks